# Subclassing custom UICollectionViewLayout to achieve certain deletion and insertion effect

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

The following is something that i wish to achieve.

1. We have a horizontal view that displays three items simultaneously.
2. when we click a button, the three items slide out of the view and are deleted. 3 more items are then created and are moved into the view to replace the previous 3 items.
3. we can keep on changing the items endlessly, even if there are only 4 items in total .

I was thinking of using collectionView to achieve this by subclassing the uicollectionviewlayout and use the following two functions.

```
 initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingDecorationElementOfKind:atIndexPath:
finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingDecorationElementOfKind:atIndexPath:
```

but i am not able to do it.. Anyone has any idea on how i can go around to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Collection views with custom layouts can be challenging to get right.  You might want to start with two horizontal `UIStackView`s, each with 3 elements, and just animate one offscreen and the other on.  It'll be a lot easier to implement for a first-pass.

Comment: @par i see.. Thanks very much for the suggestion.. I will definitely check that out to see if it would be a good solution (:

Answer (score 0):

Instead why don't you just use the horizontal flowLayout and update the data source for the collection view when the button is pressed and reload/insertCells with the moving out animation ?